# Catalina Error with Deployment with ServletContextListener

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, servlets, servletcontextlistener

i have a small problem. I´m trying to start a method on the Tomcat startup... But i can´t find my error.... Can you help me?

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>TheManager</display-name>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
       de.voltoviper.web.DBManager
    </listener-class>
</listener>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Java Class

```
package de.voltoviper.web;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class DBManager implements ServletContextListener {
    /**
     * 
     */
    SessionFactory factory;
    Session session;



    public DBManager() {
        super();
    }

    private void init() {
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("---------- DBManager Initializing ----------");
        System.out.println("----------");
        factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        session = factory.openSession();
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("---------- DBManager Initialized successfully ----------");
        System.out.println("----------");
    }

    private void destroy(){
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("---------- DBManager start closing ----------");
        System.out.println("----------");
        session.close();
        factory.close();
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("---------- DBManager closing successfully ----------");
        System.out.println("----------");
    }


    public Session getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        destroy();

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

        init();

    }
}
```

And here the Console output:

```
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TheManager' did not find a matching property.
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.26
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server built:          Aug 18 2015 11:38:37 UTC
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server number:         8.0.26.0
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: OS Name:               Windows 10
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: OS Version:            10.0
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Architecture:          amd64
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Java Home:             D:\Program Files\Java
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JVM Version:           1.8.0_60-b27
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\Entwicklung\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\Entwicklung\WEBSERVER\apache-tomcat-8.0.26
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\Entwicklung\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\Entwicklung\WEBSERVER\apache-tomcat-8.0.26
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\Entwicklung\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Entwicklung\WEBSERVER\apache-tomcat-8.0.26\endorsed
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMATION: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: D:\Program Files\Java\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;D:/Program Files/Java/bin/server;D:/Program Files/Java/bin;D:/Program Files/Java/lib/amd64;D:\Python27\;D:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\Christoph Nebendahl\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Users\Christoph Nebendahl\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts;C:\Users\Christoph Nebendahl\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Windows\system32;;.
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMATION: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMATION: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMATION: Initialization processed in 355 ms
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting service Catalina
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.26
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TheManager]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TheManager]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/SessionFactory;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:86)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.SessionFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    ... 20 more

Dez 26, 2015 8:28:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Dez 26, 2015 8:28:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SCHWERWIEGEND: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Dez 26, 2015 8:28:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMATION: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMATION: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFORMATION: Stopping service Catalina
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMATION: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SCHWERWIEGEND: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:304)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:480)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:818)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

Dez 26, 2015 8:28:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMATION: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dez 26, 2015 8:28:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SCHWERWIEGEND: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:304)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:480)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:818)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

The Problem is that everything is fine with the project when i delete the listener from the web.xml...
I thought it won´t be so hard to implement this.... I hope you guys can help me. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: the root cause seems to be `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/SessionFactory`. Do you have all needed hibernate jars in `WEB-INF/lib`?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @wero answer to your question I would like to add some additional notes. Your way of working with session is incorrect because of you have an opened session for all application's lifetime. A `Session` is not thread safe, so you can lost your data  using `getSession()` in servlets, because of each servlet works in the own separate thread.

The simplest way of working with sessions is build `SessionFactory` in `DBManager` (`DBManager` is not suitable name for such class). And open and close a session for every database operation. You can use this [pattern](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/factory/HibernateSessionFactory.java#L41) to organize a work with sessions and transactions.

Comment: hi, ladynev thanks for your replay :) I already switched to that pattern :)